# load wordpress comments on clicking on button click, not on page load

Tags: ajax, wordpress, comments

I have site http://inspire.mobi, comments are shown fine on http://inspire.mobi/why. But i need to move these comments to the home page or quotes page.

If on home page, if user clicks on the big text, then only comments will display under the video, not on the direct page load.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments

It would require an ajax call